# Golang - slice append (when needed) does not work

Tags: go, append, slice

I don't understand why append doesn't work as expected.
If the key is larger than the length, lines should be created...
Everything works fine with make (example), but this is not dynamic.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //lines := make([]string, 10, 10)
    var lines []string
    addToLine(lines, 0)
    addToLine(lines, 1)
    addToLine(lines, 2)
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(lines, "\n"))
}

func addToLine(lines []string, lNum int) {
    lNum++
    for len(lines) <= lNum {
        lines = append(lines, "")
    }
    lines[lNum] += "test line"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/K23e_suK6n_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You override `lines` internal variable inside `addToLine()` function but does not return mutated slice.

Works as expected if you return it back:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //lines := make([]string, 10, 10)
    var lines []string
    lines = addToLine(lines, 0)
    lines = addToLine(lines, 1)
    lines = addToLine(lines, 2)
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(lines, "\n"))
}

func addToLine(lines []string, lNum int) []string {
    lNum++
    for len(lines) <= lNum {
        lines = append(lines, "")
    }
    lines[lNum] += "test line"
    return lines
}
```

Comment: append() function creates a new slice. How your caller will get it you does not return? You have to return result somehow (can use channel instead of slice) to collect data from all the nodes. Check this link for sample code - https://gist.github.com/fearblackcat/02970015071e63487d964f28f78d938c

Comment: many thanks for the answers and the link! (and found a solution with return...)

Comment: another solution is to use a anonymous function instead of addToLine(). var lines []string is declared outside... :)